# Mailchimp addListMember returns client error 400 bad request when already existing

Tags: php, api, exception, mailchimp, guzzle

I'm working on adding a basic Mailchimp subscribe form to a website using their MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient() composer resource. Adding a user seems to work fine, but when trying to add somebody who already exists, i'd expect just a nice json response so that I can catch that error and display it to the user, but instead I get the following GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException:

```
Client error: `POST https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xxxxxxxxxx/members` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Member Exists","status" (truncated...)
```

The documentation doesnt really seem to explain much, I had to find the right way to catch that error from stack overflow too as Mailchimps documentation was.. lacking! Here is the code:

```
try {
    $response = $mailchimp->lists->addListMember($this->settings_helper->get('mailchimp_list_id'), [
        "email_address" => $form->get_field_value('email'),
        "status" => "subscribed",
        "merge_fields" => [
            "FNAME" => $first_name,
            "LNAME" => $last_name
         ]
    ]);
    
    if ($response->getId()) {
        $this->add_json_success($this->settings_helper->get('mailchimp_success_message'));
    }
} catch (MailchimpMarketing\ApiException $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the mailchimp documentation I used: https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/list-members/add-member-to-list/

I could just catch the error code of 400 and output a custom error but i'm sure that I must be doing soemthing wrong to get such an unhelpful response from the Mailchimp API?

Many thanks, andy and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, so I ended up directing the error message to see what the whole error was by changing your last catch clause to the following:

```
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
  echo '<pre>' . var_export($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()).'</pre>';
  $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

This revealed the following crappy error, which was up to this point truncated:

```
{
    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title":"Invalid Resource",
    "status":400,
    "detail":"Isabell_Murazik@example.com looks fake or invalid, please enter a real email address.",
    "instance":"fcc1d762-2475-40a6-bc7f-4ac7f3fb7902"
}
```

So, my issue was that `@example.com` looks fake or invalid...

Trying a different email, even a `@test.com` worked.
I cannot promise you this will be your issue as well, but checking the error details is definitely a good first step!

Comment: The spammy email was the case for my. Was testing using yopmail.com

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this.

To display the various key values use your own variation on this

```
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $decoded = json_decode($responseBodyAsString);
        echo $decoded->title;
}
```